# Probability of offsetting errors

Tags: probability

Installing or modifying complicated equipment sometimes requires verifying that multi-wired cable harnesses match documented specifications. These are called continuity tests.  **At my work one day, a discussion arose about the benefits and liabilities of testing a pair of harnesses connected together versus one at a time**.  Testing a pair of harnesses connected together takes only half the time of testing them individually.  But we must consider associated risks before proceeding.

The drawing below shows 3 pairs of wire harnesses.  Each harness has a plug at one end and a socket at the other so pairs can easily be tested together or individually. Assume a device requires that all connections go straight across as shown in the **top drawing** named "**Pair of Perfect Harnesses**".   Here there are no mistakes to be found whether the harnesses are tested together or individually.

If one of the harnesses has a mistake as shown in the **middle drawing** named "**Pair of Harnesses With a Single Mistake**".  This mistake will be detected whether the harnesses are tested together or individually.  Considering these first 2 drawings, both testing options seem reasonable.

However, a possibility exists that both harnesses have equal and opposite mistakes as shown in the **bottom drawing** named, "**Pair of Harnesses With Two Offsetting Mistakes**".  In this scenario testing the harnesses while connected would not reveal either of these mistakes. This may seem fine for the moment but would surely cause trouble later since cables and modules are swapped in and out of systems frequently.  Although they function as a pair, either of these harnesses would fail if matched up with any other harness.   It appears we must test the harnesses individually unless we can demonstrate that the probability of this third scenario is small enough to dismiss.

[image]

Considering the drawing above named "**Pair of Harnesses With Two Offsetting Mistakes**".  Assume that each of two harnesses has a single mistake and that all mistakes are equally likely to occur.  Assume the harnesses has N wires and the sockets and plugs have N pins to accommodate N wires.  As such, we will **define a mistake as any 2 wires being swapped** at either the plug or the socket but not both.  Remember that any pair of wires can be swapped and that this mistake will only be offset when the exact same two wires are swapped in the other harness at either the socket or the plug.  Let us define the probability of making this mistake p.

1. **What is the probability (in terms of N and p) that mistakes in each
   of the harnesses will offset each other as shown in the bottom
   drawing?**

Now let’s modify the description above by using sockets and plugs that accommodate 2N wires as shown in the image below.  This means that half of the pins will be used and half will be left unconnected.  Now we will **define a mistake as attaching a single wire in the socket or plug to a pin that should remain unconnected**.  Any single misconnected wire can create a mistake in one harness and now only that same wire misconnected to the same wrong pin of the other harness will offset the original mistake.  Let us define the probability of making this mistake q.

[image]

2. **What is the probability (in terms of N and q) that mistakes in each of the harnesses will offset each other as shown in the 2N drawing
   above?**

Comment: Is it 1/m * 1/n ?

Comment: Maybe 1/m * (m-n)/m * 1/n